# Upgrading gradle plugin version to 7.0.0 causes issues with HiltTestRunner

Tags: android

I am using HiltTestRunner like below

```
class HiltTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

   override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?):Application 
   {
      return super.newApplication(cl,InstrumentedTestApplication_Application::class.java.name, context)}
   }
```

I upgraded gradle plugin version from 4.1.1 to 7.0.0 and after that I am getting the following error

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not create task ':features:search:lintAnalyzeDebug'.
> > Source directory '\HiltTestRunner.kt' is not a directory.

This only happened after I upgraded.

Comment: Which hilt version are you using?

Comment: I am using hilt 2.38.1

Comment: try to `invalidate cache / restart`

Comment: already did that.